# Ошибка TypeError: Dispatcher.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, aiogram

Пишу Телеграмм бота на pythone. Выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Project\pythonProject\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    dp = Dispatcher(bot)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Dispatcher.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Мои импорты

```
import logging

import executor as executor
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
```

Ну и часть кода

```
bot = Bot(token="*****************************")

dp = Dispatcher(bot)
```

Comment: а что вы делаете дальше? Представленный код никак не отражает природы происхождения ошибки.